# Using pylint with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I downloaded Visual Studio Code the other day and I decided to use it with pylint.

For some odd reason I couldn't set the python interpreter to python 3 from the palette (Shift + Ctrl + P) but I set the path to it from the settings and it seems to have done the job. However, pylint underlines almost everything. All of my imports are underlined with the error message:

**[pylint] E0401:Unable to import 'my.import'**

I read a couple of threads on this topic and the main suggestions are to set the correct python path and path to pylint, which I have done with 0 success. I tried removing it `pip3 remove pylint` and reinstalling it, however, it still did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try setting `"python.linting.pylintPath"` key separately.

In `settings.json` you can set like this;

```
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/user/.local/bin/pylint"
```

user will be your user name of course

if you use linux and want to find exact location of pylint you can run `which pylint` command in terminal

Comment: How would the asker set the key separately? Please include more details in your answer.

Comment: Surprisingly, adding the correct pylintPath in the VS Code User Settings cleared my import error message. Could please explain why this works?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what causes this problem at the beginning. My only guess is that VS Code couldn't fetch pylint location to use it. So adding pylint path manually would override the default behavior and solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue, you can set the path to your python installation in preferences-> settings `python.pythonPath`.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I have already set the python path from the settings to python3 and it has not done much.